# Installing videosequence package for python

Tags: python, importerror

I downloaded videosequence package from [Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/videosequence/1.1.0)

After that, I ran`python setup.py install` from the downloaded folder and then I ran simple script containing only one line `from videosequence import VideoSequence` and got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "videoseq.py", line 2, in <module>
    from videosequence import VideoSequence
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/videosequence/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require_version'
```

Would be grateful for any help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you did not install the [`PyGObject introspection`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject) library required :

> Caveats
>
> Iterating forward one frame at a time is fast. Tricks such as iterating backwards or skipping n frames at a time work but is likely
>   to be slow.
>
> The implementation is based on GStreamer and so de facto only works on a modern Unix-alike such as Linux or FreeBSD.
>
> **The PyGObject introspection libraries must be installed. (See below.)**

Try to run from the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 \
                   python-gi python3-gi
```

Also, the GStreamer module is required if not installed:

```
$ sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```